# ApacheKafka Appender logback

Tags: java, apache-kafka, logback, slf4j

I just started playing with it with ApacheKafka. I set the whole thing up and now I am trying to introduce Kafka sending logs via log appender in already existing Java application. This application is using Logback as a logger library. So, I guess, that makes me impossible to use `kafka.producer.KafkaLog4jAppender`? There are not compatible? I am getting  `IncompatibleClassException`. Is there maybe other solution? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use logback-kafka appender available.

Check this [link](https://github.com/danielwegener/logback-kafka-appender)

Comment: Do you trust sending logs directly to Kafka? What about network failures and backpressure? Isn't it better to log to local file and have a log agent ship them to Kafka?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good [Logback Appender that sends log messages to Kafka](https://github.com/johnmpage/logback-kafka). It has a powerful, light-weight approach that allows you to make full use of the latest Kafka Producer.